# Does Investiture of Stone work at the "end" of a fall?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, grapple

My friend and I tried a mock fight and something very strange rule wise happened. My character is equipped with boots of levitation and grappled his character. We floated up for two turns. He spent his turns casting investiture of stone and dispel (on boots effect).

When we fell he stated that he would fall through the ground and take no damage but I stated that he has to use his own movement to use investiture of stone's effect and since he was grappled he could not. How would this situation work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Investiture of Stone doesn't mention anything about letting you pass through the ground while falling, nor does it mention anything about reflexively falling through stone.

It *does* mention:

> You can move through solid earth or stone as if it was air and without destabilizing it, but you can’t end your movement there

Given that he has considerable momentum, and there is nothing to stop him, the spell seems to give no options for him to "fall through the ground" as he can't stay in the ground, but he also has no way to brake and move back above ground.

The only logical way of reading this spell is that it allows voluntary, controlled movement through earth/stone but if you fall, you still go splat.

Comment: The key issue I saw in the question had to do with the movement = 0 when grappled.  Do you feel that you addressed that?

Comment: I don't think his movement speed matters at all - this spell cannot prevent you from splattering on the ground, grappled or not.

Comment: The reason I ask is that during a turn you can take actions and move.  I think someone can argue that falling isn't your movement action -- maybe it is -- so that upon arrival at "the ground" the person could move through the ground and then reappear above the ground ... If They Had Enough Movement to do so.  Since movement = 0, that option is foreclosed.  (I do like your answer, but I think he raised the point about movement for a reason, perhaps to do with action economy)

Comment: The problem is that even if you're opting to fall through the ground, you won't stop.   While moving like that, you treat the ground like air, not water, so there's no braking option. The only way you can stop moving is by treating the ground as solid, at which point you take the falling damage.

Comment: I see your point.

Comment: As a DM, I'd almost allow if it were vs my NPC just because it was so creative.